# TypeError: ufunc 'expi' not supported for input type, and input can't be safely coerced to supported type according to casting rule ''safe''

Tags: arcpy, raster-calculator

Here is my code for raster calculation in ArcGIS. However, I am getting raster file for "uw" only. The python is unable to calculate exponential integral of raster uw. Thus, I am not getting the required result which I expect after calculation as raster4. Any help from the experts would be of great help to me.

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env
from arcpy.sa import *
import numpy as np
from scipy import special as sp
from scipy.special import expi

##### parameters####
rw = 0.15
S = 0.003
t = 30

#### raster band selection ####
raster1 = Raster('allowable head')
raster2 = Raster('Transmissivity')

##### well function calculation ###
uw = rw**2 * S / (4 * raster2 * t)

#### calculate exponential integral of well function ######
W_uw = -sp.expi(-uw)

##### capacity calculation ####
raster4 = (raster1 * raster2 * 4 * np.pi * t) / W_uw
```

expi in the code refers to "exponential integral" mathematical function which is used to solve the Euler's series. The code is executing up to "uw" only. I receive a raster output of "uw" and nothing after that.

I edited the code as per the suggestion of @Hornbydd:

```
##### well function calculation ###
uw = rw**2 * S / (4 * raster2 * t)

#### Convert Raster to numpy array
arr = arcpy.RasterToNumPyArray(uw,nodata_to_value=0)
### expi of array
arrexpi = -sp.expi(-arr)

# Convert Array to raster (keep origin and cellsize the same as the input)
newRaster = arcpy.NumPyArrayToRaster(arrexpi, 
                                     lowerleft,cellSize,value_to_nodata=0)
```

However, I still get the value of uw only and noting after that. How to set lowerleft value? Is it the X-cordinate and Y-cordinate? Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've never used scipy but looking at the help file for [expi()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.expi.html) it says the input is an array and if you follow the code sample it works on the array they demonstrate with.

Now if you type

```
type(uw)
```

after the line that creates `uw`, it returns **raster** and not **array**. I suspect thats the source of your problem?

You can convert raster into arrays using this function [RasterToNumPyArray()](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.7/analyze/arcpy-functions/rastertonumpyarray-function.htm) and back into Rasters using the appropriate function.